# Do you know an example where uses MVVM and factories?

Tags: c#, mvvm, viewmodel, factory-pattern

I'm using MVVM and also the pattern Factory.

My factory create several models at the beginning. Then I realized that I need to factor the viewmodel of the model.

Do you have examples of this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Create Your FactoryClass in your solution and use it in in your Program...mvvm is a UI  pattern  and Does not Depend to Factory Pattern